# How to get ForeignKey model field

Tags: python, django, django-models

In Django 1.8

```
class OtherModel(models.Model):
    somefield = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Orderform(models.Model):
    sell_item_id = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Selled(models.Model):
    orderform = models.ForeignKey("Orderform")
    sell_count = models.IntegerField()
    something = OtherModel.objects.get(id=sell_item_id)
```

I need to use something like `OtherModel.objects.get(id=sell_item_id)`.

How to get `sell_item_id` in `class Selled(models.Model):`?

Comment: refer to the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/#many-to-one-relationships)

Comment: What is `OtherModel`?

Comment: no use the ForeignKey model

Answer (score 1):

You schema couldn't be presented in SQL.

**Option #1:**

```
class Orderform(models.Model):
    sell_item_id = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    othermodel = models.OneToOneField("OtherModel")
```

and get it

```
Selled.objects.get(pk=1).orderform.othermodel
```

**Option #2:**

```
class Selled(models.Model):
    orderform = models.ForeignKey("Orderform")
    sell_count = models.IntegerField()

    def something(self):
        return OtherModel.objects.get(id=self.sell_item_id)
```

and get

```
Selled.objects.get(pk=1).something()
```

But I think you should better think about you DB schema.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a couple of questions, for the first, to get the related

```
Selled.objects.filter(order_form__sell_item_id =id_to_get).select_related('order_form')
```

Notice the `__` (double underscore) before `sell_item_id`. This is important because it says, selected `Selleed` by the `sell_item_id` of the `OrderForm`. and `select_related` makes sure that order form is brought back in the results with a single call to the db.

Now, if you want to do that for `OtherModel`, you will need to create a similar `ForeignKey` field in the `OtherNodel` and this will allow you to make the same query as above. Currently, you have no such relation.

```
class OtherModel(models.Model):
    somefield = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    orderform = models.ForeignKey("Orderform")

OtherModel.objects.filter(order_form__sell_item_id =id_to_get).select_related('order_form')
```

Don't forget to run:

```
python manage.py makemigration
python manage.py migrate
```

This should solve the issue.